# chrome.webrequest.onCompleted vs. chrome.runtime.onMessage race

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, race-condition

I have a Chrome extension with a `background.js` where information about a page is collected and stored,

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
  function(details) {
  // compute a page hash etc, store it
  tabToHash[details.tabId] = hash;
  },
{
  urls: ['*://*/*.pdf'],
  types: ['main_frame']
}
);
```

and served to any other part of extension that asks for it (e.g., a content script),

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.getInfo) {
      sendResponse({
        hash: tabToHash[sender.tab.id],
      });
    }
  });
```

A problem now occurs when `onMessage` is fired before `onCompleted` has completed.

How to avoid this race condition?

---

*Edit:*
A content script that sends the initial message might contain

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
  {getInfo: true},
  function(response) {
  // do something with the response
  }
);
```

and could be inserted in the `manifest.json` as

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*.pdf"],
      "css": ["content.css"],
      "js": ["scripts/content.js"]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Critical code missing (how is the message sent?)

Comment: `sendResponse` -- it's right there.

Comment: No, that's a reply. How is that `onMessage` code triggered? Otherwise we know nothing about relative timing. Please include a _complete_ example so that we can see the logic flow.

Comment: Well, I can of course put the send code from the content script in as well, but I figure not much information comes from that. The issue really is that `onMessage` can be triggered before `onCompleted` has completed, indepentently of _how_ exactly it's triggered.

Comment: Look, your question is about timing. We need: 1) how you inject the content script, 2) how content script calls the background, 3) what filter is set for `webRequest`.

Comment: "onMessage can be triggered before onCompleted has completed" Well, in that case you won't have information. As easy as that. Hash can be stale, too, not just undefined. You need to modify the logic, possibly heavily - but we can't help, as it relies on the code you haven't shown.

Comment: Okay, I've added some bits; let me know if you'd like to see anything else.

Comment: Yes, final bit would be how the content script is injected - via manifest? Do you specify `run_at`?

Comment: Added that bit, too. (I didn't even know there's more than one method to inject it.) Mind you that in the future I might want to `sendMessage` in a popup script, too (certainly this gets exectuted late though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Track the loading status of the content by adding

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {
    tabStatus[details.tabId] = 'loading';
  },
  {
    urls: ['*://*/*.pdf'],
    types: ['main_frame']
  }
);
```

and

```
tabStatus[details.tabId] = 'complete';
```

at the end of `chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener`

- Conditionally defer the response in the `onMessage` listener:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.getInfo) {
      if (tabStatus[sender.tab.id] === 'complete') {
        // send immediately
        sendResponse({
          data: myData[sender.tab.id]
        });
      } else {
        // send later
        responseSender[sender.tab.id] = sendResponse;
        // returning `true` to indicate that we intend to send later,
        // cf. <https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage>
        return true;
      }
    }
  });
```

- Call the stored `responseSender[sender.tab.id]` at the end of `chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener`:

```
if (responseSender[details.tabId]) {
  responseSender[details.tabId]({
    data: myData(details.tabId)
  });
  responseSender[details.tabId] = null;
}
```

Comment: Downvoting since this is formally not a useful answer. However, I can tell you what's wrong here. Asynchronously calling `sendResponse` requires you to return `true` from the `onMessage` listener - a way to tell Chrome "yes, I intend to answer later".

Comment: Yes! Adding `return true` indeed fixes it.